# MIPS Error Message

Tags: assembly, mips

The program prompts the user to enter a natural number, which it then does a calculation recursively. The base case is: if(n=0 or n=1 or n=2) return 2. So if n is less than 0, the program should output an error message to the console for the user to enter another natural number again. Here is my code:

```
Loop:

    la $a0, Prompt  #loads the address of the label named Prompt
    li $v0, 4   #uses the Operation Code $v0, 4; which is Print_string. This will allow the user to see the string. This is equivalent to cout << "Enter the natural number:" << endl; in C
    syscall
    li $v0, 5   #uses the Operation Code $v0, 5; which is Read_int. This will read in what the user entered for the constant value. This is equivalent to cin >> NaturalNumber; in C
    syscall


    #Place the value entered by the user into $a0
    move $a0, $v0


    #Allocate space
    addi $sp, $sp, -4
    sw $ra, 0($sp)
    jal Func    #Jump and Link to Func

    #Deallocate Space
    lw $ra, 0($sp)
    addi $sp, $sp, 4

    #save the return value of the function
    move $s0, $v0


    #Show the result message
    la $a0, Result_Message  #loads the address of the label named Result_Message
    li $v0, 4       #uses the Operation Code $v0, 4; which is Print_string. This will allow the user to see the string. This is equivalent to cout << "The result is:" << endl; in C
    syscall

    #Print the result
    move $a0, $s0
    li $v0, 1   #uses the Operation Code $v0,1, which is Print_int. This will allow the integer to be printed to the console. This is equivalent to cout << $a0 in C-pseudo-code;
    syscall

    la $a0, NextLine
    li $v0, 4
    syscall

    j Loop

    jr $ra
```

The `bltz $v0, TryAgain` code below is supposed to go to the label `TryAgain` in my `.data` section to prompt the user to try again, but for some reason I keep getting an error message. Why? Thanks in advance!

```
Func:

    addi $sp, $sp, -24
    sw $ra, 0($sp)
    sw $a0, 4($sp)
    sw $s1, 8($sp)


    #Create a sentinel value
    li $t8, 999
    beq $v0, $t8, finish    #if the user enters 999 as a value, the program will terminate

    **bltz    $v0, TryAgain        # terminate if n < 0**

    slti $t0, $a0, 3
    beq $t0, $zero, else



    #return 2   
    addi $v0, $zero, 2
    j return

else:

    addi $a0, $a0, -2
    jal Func

    #$s1 = (-3) * func($a0-2)
    addi $t1, $zero, -3
    mult $t1, $v0
    mflo $s1

    #func($a0-3)
    addi $a0, $a0, -1
    jal Func

    # $t3= 7 * func($a0-3)
    addi $t2, $zero, 7
    mult $t2, $v0
    mflo $t3

    #$v0 = $t4 + 15 = $s1 +$t3 +15 = (-3) * func($a0 -2) +7
    add $t4, $s1, $t3
    addi $v0, $t4, 15


return:
    lw $s1, 8($sp)
    lw $a0, 4($sp)
    lw $ra, 0($sp)
    addi $sp, $sp, 24

    jr $ra

finish: 

    li $v0, 10  #uses the Operation Code $v0, 10; which is Exit. This terminates the program. This is equivalent to return 0; in C
    syscall
```

Comment: It would probably help if you included the error message.  Also, why is this tagged C++ and java?  I don't see anything but mips assembly.  Also, this can't be your whole code.  I don't see TryAgain defined anywhere.  And if it's really a label in the data section, branching to it is a terrible idea.  Don't put code in the data section, and don't try to run non-code.

Comment: Reduce this down to minimal testcase that demonstrates the problem you're having.  You have a giant amount of code that doesn't appear to be needed to reproduce the exact problem you're having.